# How to create a PDF exactly like a page with puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

Some html and css elements are lost, the page is divided to fit the A4 format and a margin is added automatically.

How do I fix this to look like the png but keeping the links using the puppeteer?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf',printBackground:true});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO5Xq.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

```
      const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto('https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
          await page.emulateMedia('screen')
          let height = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement.offsetHeight);
          await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf',printBackground: true, height: height + 'px'});
          await browser.close();
        })();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but maybe pdfmyurl.com may help you.
The page is exactly the same and links works too. The only problem is fit to A4 Page.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i needed this in the puppeteer for my project.